# missing jdk when using java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto

Tags: java, aws-cloudformation

I have this error:

```
Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/jre contains a valid JDK installation.
```

in the cloudformation template, i have:

```
        extras:
          commands:
            'a_enable_docker':
              command: 'amazon-linux-extras enable docker=18.06.1'
              test: "! grep -Fxq '[amzn2extra-docker]' /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn2-extras.repo"
            'b_enable_corretto8':
              command: 'amazon-linux-extras enable corretto8'
              test: "! grep -Fxq '[amzn2extra-corretto8]' /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn2-extras.repo"
        install:
          packages:
            rpm:
              jenkins: 'https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins-2.176.3-1.1.noarch.rpm'
            yum:
              'java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto': []
              'ruby': []
```

https://github.com/widdix/aws-cf-templates/blob/master/jenkins/jenkins2-ha-agents.yaml#L1734-L1737

so, java is installed,

```
[root@ip-10-1-15-79 ~]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.222.10.2 (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.222.10.2 (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
[root@ip-10-1-15-79 ~]# yum info java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Available Packages
Name        : java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.8.0_222.b10
Release     : 2.amzn2
Size        : 64 M
Repo        : amzn2extra-corretto8/2/x86_64
Summary     : Amazon Corretto development environment
URL         : https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8
Licence     : ASL 1.1 and ASL 2.0 and BSD and BSD with advertising and GPL+ and GPLv2 and GPLv2 with exceptions and IJG and LGPLv2+ and MIT and MPLv2.0 and Public Domain and W3C and zlib.
Description : Amazon Corretto's packaging of the OpenJDK 8 code.
```

but how do i add jdk?

any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel` to get the JDK, without that trailing `devel` it's just a JRE